# Angular2 component doesn't update when data becomes available

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components, angular2-observables

I have a component with attributes bound to a data property.

```
@Component({
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
 selector: 'animal-detail-main',
 styleUrls: ['animal-detail-main.component.scss'],
 template: `
      <div>
        {{data | json}}
      </div>
      `
})

export class DetailMain  {
  data: any;

 private dataSvc: MainService;

 constructor( 
    @Inject(MainService)  dataSvc: MainService,
    ) {
      this.dataSvc = dataSvc;
    }

  ngOnInit() {
        var fetchedData: any;

        this.dataSvc.currentID$
           .subscribe(
              currentID => {
                   currentID = currentID;
                   this.dataSvc
                     .getDetail(currentID)
                     .map(response => response.json())
                     .subscribe (
                         data => {fetchedData = data[0]},
                          err => console.log('Error',err),
                          () => {
                          console.log('fetchedData',fetchedData);
                          setTimeout(() => {
                             this.data = fetchedData;
                             console.log("this.data",this.data);
                          }, 2000);
                    }
           );
      });   
 }
}
```

Basically the currentID$ service holds an ID for the current object, so that's fetched back into currentID, and then currentID is passed into the getDetail service to return the entire object for that ID.

Without the setTimeout, the function returns the object data late and it never gets assigned to this.data.

With the setTimeout, the console.log right after this.data is assigned the fetchData returned object correctly logs the returned object, but the view never updates so the data isn't displayed in the component.

I expected that the component would auto-magically refresh once the data became available, but it doesn't, and I don't know how to trigger an update of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use `flatMap` here to chain the requests, as the second one is dependent on the Observable from your service. EDIT. This works well if your id is a `BehaviorSubject`.

```ts
constructor(private dataSvc: MainService) { }

data: any = {}; // if it's an object

ngOnInit() {
   this.dataSvc.currentID$
     .flatMap(currentId => this.dataSvc.getDetail(currentId))
        .map(res => res.json()) // could do the mapping in the service
        .subscribe(data => {
           this.data = data[0];
        });
}
```

About the view not updating, not being entirely sure about that.... Try the above solution, if the template is not updated, you could try and trigger the change detection manually with [**`ChangeDetectorRef`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detectChanges-anchor), but I don't really see why the change detection wouldn't happen. But these things just seem to happen sometimes :)

Comment: When I try this the variables don't get updated at all at the end of the stack. What I'm doing now is removing the first Observable that gets the currentID, and passing that as a parameter via URL through the Router, and then using that to fetch the data. This seems to work, but I'm still confused as to why chaining the Observables, which gets the data and displays on the console, doesn't update the Component view. I'd much rather use a service to maintain the currentID instead of passing the params via URL.

Comment: Right yes, you are probably using `Subject`, you'd need to use `BehaviorSubject` in this case to trigger the above code. Did you try the change detector mentioned in answer? Here's a plunker with behaviorsubject and changedetector: http://plnkr.co/edit/U9ZlO3yvr9rkjzQ6DuYL?p=preview. As to why the chaining of your code seems not to work, hmm. First of all, is pretty bad practice to do a subscription inside subscription because of the "unpredictable nature" of subscriptions, this might actually have something to do with your issue...

Comment: BehaviorSubject was the missing piece there - I wasn't aware of flatMap or BehaviorSubject. Thanks - this helps a lot!